# Ionic File Transfer: How to add params to download url

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I need download pdf file from the server. And with url, I need to pass custom params like branch id, company id. there are options for file upload to add custom params, but nothing for download. Here is my code

```
let pdfParams ={
    "branch":"GST DEMO",
    "company":"GST DEMO",
    "finyr":"2017-2018",
}
const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
const url = 
 "http://192.168.125.75:32923/mfginventory/mobileserviceapi/ereportpdfGET";
let uri = encodeURI(url);
fileTransfer.download(uri,this.file.externalRootDirectory+'file.pdf') 
   .then((entry) => {
       console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
    }, (error) => {
       console.log(error);
    });
```

My url should be like

```
"http://192.168.125.75:32923/mfginventory/mobileserviceapi/ereportpdfGET?PID=1500966148428&params="+JSON.stringify(pdfParams);
```

but if i give like this it is showing error "HTTP version not supported". Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: are you performing this operation in a component(i mean a routing page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.stringify(pdfParams) returns:

```
"{"branch":"GST DEMO","company":"GST DEMO","finyr":"2017-2018"}"
```

so your url ends up being:

```
"http://192.168.125.75:32923/mfginventory/mobileserviceapi/ereportpdfGET?PID=1500966148428&params={"branch":"GST DEMO","company":"GST DEMO","finyr":"2017-2018"}"
```

That's not a vaild format. I'm guessing the final URL should look something like this?

```
http://192.168.125.75:32923/mfginventory/mobileserviceapi/ereportpdfGET?PID=1500966148428&branch=GST+DEMO&company=GST+DEMO&finyr=2017-2018
```

Depending on what browsers you need to support, you could try the URLSearchParams method to get there. If you need IE support, there are a lot of simple functions for this on SO.

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(pdfParams);
const fullUrl = "http://192.168.125.75:32923/mfginventory/mobileserviceapi/ereportpdfGET?PID=1500966148428&" + searchParams
```

Comment: Thanks, @SimonW for let me know of URLSearchParams() method. Your solution worked Partially. I made some changes and it worked correctly then.